# Gradle returns package does not exists

Tags: java, android, gson, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to add the gson library to my android project (I'm devloping using the Andrdoid-studio).

To add the library, I changed the AppProject/AppName/build.gradle file in this way:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

It seems to work until I try to use it.

When I try to include it with:

```
import com.google.code.gson;
```

Gradle complains affirming:

```
Gradle: error: package com.google does not exist
```

Comment: This question solved my problem - I added the library in studio but the dependency in Gradle file was missing. Works now.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but this did:

- Download the GSON JAR file and copy it to your /libs/ folder inside your application project.
- Open the build.gradle file at the root level of your project and edit your dependencies to include the new .jar file:

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }
  ```
- Build -> Rebuild Project

Optionally, you can specify one or more specific JAR files with files rather than fileTree, such as: 
    `compile files('libs/google-gson-1.7.1/gson-1.7.1.jar')`

Answer (score 3):

One solution that might be helpful is to try **Syncing Project with Gradle Files**

**Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files**

Comment: Nah, that doesn't resolve this error in a library module.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects this happens sometimes in the `:javadoc` task.
If you do not need the `:javadoc` task you can ignore it with:

`./gradlew :install -x :javadoc`

Comment: In my case `-x :app:androidJavadocs`