# Gradle: package com.parse does not exist

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to add the Parse SDK into my app. Here is the steps I took:

1. Dragged all Parse files into my libs folder
2. Add the following lines to my code:

   ```
   import com.parse.Parse;
   import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
   ```
3. Went to my build.gradle and added:

   ```
   compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.1-javadoc/Parse-1.4.1.jar')
   ```

However I am still getting these errors:

```
Gradle: package com.parse does not exist
Gradle: package com.parse does not exist
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918347/gradle-returns-package-does-not-exists?rq=1

Comment: Is that the only line you've added to your build.gradle? Because that is only compiling the java doc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.1-javadoc/Parse-1.4.1.jar')` to `compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.1.jar')`

Answer (score 1):

If you see your jar file in explorer on the left side, click right button of your mouse and then 'Add as Library'. It just helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Parse-SDK into my app as follows:

**Dependency:** Add this in your root build.gradle file (not your module build.gradle file):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Then, add the library to your project build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:*latest.version.here*"
    // for FCM Push support (optional)
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:*latest.version.here*"
    // for Kotlin extensions support (optional)
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:*latest.version.here*"
}
```

replacing *latest.version.here* with the latest released version (in my case 1.18.5).

More details here: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/. 
I am not to sure if that achieves the same purpose as what you wanted.